# Dependence of reaction rate on concentrations and stoichiometric coefficients of reactants and products

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Consider a general equation of a reaction:

$$
\ce{aA + bB -> \text{Products}}
$$

We can say, in chemical kinetics, that the rate of the reaction is:

$$
\text{Rate} = k([\ce{A}]^a [\ce{B}]^b)
$$

where $\ce{[A]}$, $\ce{[B]}$ are the concentrations or active masses of the reactants.

My question is, why is the rate of reaction proportional to the concentrations of the reactants **raised to the power of their stoichiometric coefficients** ?

(Not really the point of the question, but why **to the power** and not just a **product** of the coefficients?)

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23642/in-the-elementary-steps-of-a-reaction-why-do-we-assume-that-the-coefficients-of, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38167/do-coefficients-matter-in-rate-law